# How to recreate this effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

Came across this while just going Google Assistant, and it looked really nice. TO me it looks like some app filter but I don't exactly know what to call this effect, so Google was of no use. Also tried reverse googling the image itself, but only gave me the article.

[image: Colourised sketch]

I'm somewhat knowledgeable in Photoshop, so any help to recreate this in PS would be much appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: I don't know about this exact look, but there are [many PS actions](https://graphicriver.net/graphics-with-sketch-in-add-ons/photoshop) that convert photos into pretty convincing looking drawings. You might want to try your luck there.

Comment: @Joonas - I agree, it looks like something possibly even created using the Prisma app for Android and iOS.  I'm sure I've seen something similar there. It uses AI filters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this image was made by AI-powered style transfer app: basically a style is extracted from a donor image (probably some watercolor painting) and applied to a source image (a car) to get the target image with this particular style. This *effect* isn't available in Photoshop but there're plenty of web-services, stand-alone apps and PS plugins that could do that. Some examples:

- a web service https://deepart.io/
- a part of a standalone app / plugin for Photoshop: https://topazlabs.com/ai-remix/

if you're into coding you can build your own style-transfering app using PyTorch for example, here's [a tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/neural_style_tutorial.html)

Comment: This looks really interesting! I didn't know this sort of thing was so easily accessible now.

I am still hoping this particular effect would be possible with Photoshop cause both the options are pretty expensive. It kind of reminds me of the filters from the Prisma app, so here's hoping.

Comment: yup, Prisma uses the same tech. There're probably free versions. I think deepart.io is free, they just sell prints of the generated images?

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy I agree, it really looks like something made with Prisma.

Comment: I was thinking Deepart when I saw this

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy Ah!! That makes sense. I didn't see any mention of using AI on their app page, so assumed it was generic filters like the rest. And I've been trying out deepart.io last night and it is free, I was confused with the print selling part yesterday before replying to you.

Answer (score 0):

You have got already an answer which suggests advanced methods. Here's something more basic.

Apply a crayon or pencil filter. I happen to have some plugins for Photoshop. This is one of them. It keeps some colors, but that's not important. A single color or greyscale version is enough:

[image]

Freeware programs GIMP and Paint.NET have numerous such filters included and much more as free add-ons.

As you see, the filter doesn't properly recognize which parts in the image belong to the same object. Thus the objects aren't well separated. You would get better separation by manually clipping major objects to their own layers and filtering them separately. Some parts seem to be clipped totally off, for ex. the front mask.

Curves and colorizing adjustment layers are inserted to get a good single color version which can be recolored:

[image]

Finally the coloring layer is inserted. Creating it needs some real artistic capability. I jumped over that problem by stealing the hues. It's a blurred version of your example. Its hue and saturation are transferred to grey with blending modes. It's inserted on the top with blending mode Hue:

[image]

This is the result:

[image]

Here's a version based on different filtering, the hues are the same:

[image]

As you see these versions are far from your example. Even a remotely resembling filtering isn't easy to find and there's surely also made some manual edits to reduce the clutter.